# How do I get my hidden field values on Postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my java script

```
 $('#geoLocation').click(function () {
        alert("I am Here");
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            // Get Latitude and Longitude
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        }
        else {
            // Hide Locator Panel, if Browser not supported
            document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    function showPosition(position) {
        //  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        // "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
          document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
          document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;


    }
```

I need to get at the latitude and longitude values (which are hidden on the screen), in Postback on the CodeBehind. How do I do this?

Comment: What are they divs not input fields? Try using input type=hidden. Only input elements are posted back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `$('#HiddenFieldId').val()` to assign data to **HiddenField** at client side.

```
<div id="geoLocation">Click me to retrieve Geo Location</div>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="LatitudeHiddenField" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="LongitudeHiddenField" />

<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#geoLocation').click(function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            // Get Latitude and Longitude
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, geoLocationErrors);
        } else {
            // Hide Locator Panel, if Browser not supported
            document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            $('#<%= LatitudeHiddenField.ClientID %>').val(position.coords.latitude);
            $('#<%= LongitudeHiddenField.ClientID %>').val(position.coords.longitude);    
        }    

        function geoLocationErrors() {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support Geo Location.");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Then you can retrieve those value from **HiddenField** at server side as -

```
var latitute = LatitudeHiddenField.Value;
var longitude = LongitudeHiddenField.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'latitude' and 'longitude' are HTML elements on the page ?

That being the case, you should be able to add a runat="server" attribute to them and then they will be available in server-side code. If you're site is ASP.NET 4/4.5 you can also add ClientIDMode="Static" and your showPosition function will work as it is; if not you could a class to them and use a jQuery class selector to get your two items.